# Save emoji unicode characters in mysql database with hibernate from spring application

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, unicode

I have a web application developed with spring, hibernate and mysql as database.

While I am trying to input an emoji unicode character like "" from a for a form then I got an exception like

```
SQL Error: 1366, SQLState: HY000
Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x80' for column 'column_name' at row 1

Handler execution resulted in exception
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateJdbcException: JDBC exception on Hibernate data access: SQLException for SQL [/* insert com.sdfasf.domain.ProductReport */ insert into product_report (issolved, isvalid, product_id, report_account_id, report_comment, report_date, solve_account_id, solve_comment, solve_date) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; SQL state [HY000]; error code [1366]; could not insert: [com.sdfasf.domain.ProductReport]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [com.sdfasf.domain.ProductReport]
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:645)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:102)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:368)
```

I change the jdbc url like

```
jdbc:mysql://${database.host}/${database.name}?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;amp;useUnicode=true&amp;amp;characterEncoding=utf8mb4
```

And Database CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci, table CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci and column collation utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Comment: If you're using Connector/J < 5.1.47 then you might need to update it https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html

Answer (score 1):

So they fix for this is to add the following the your my.ini then restart the mysql server.

```
character-set-server=utf8mb4
default-character-set=utf8mb4
```

If you have databases that need migration, see here: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4

Be sure to also update hibernate values: 
`<property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet" value="utf8mb4" />
<property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="utf8mb4"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true"/>`

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE ... CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
```

Note:  the database and table character sets are just `DEFAULTs`, they are *not* necessarily what the columns are using.

`Incorrect string value: '\xF0...` definitely calls for utf8mb4, not just utf8.

Comment: Let's see the spring/hibernate config that specifies `UTF-8`, etc.  And the `ALTER` that you did.

Comment: `hibernate.connection.useUnicode=true`
`hibernate.connection.charSet=utf8mb4`

Comment: Perhaps also `hibernate.connection.characterEncoding=utf-8`, `<form accept-charset="UTF-8">`.  And I am not clear whether the one you mentioned should be 'MySQL' -- `utf8mb4` (as you list), or 'rest of the world' -- `UTF-8`.  Another note mentions `<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/miniprojetjee?useUnicode=true&connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci&characterSetResults=utf8&characterEncoding=utf-8"/>` and `@RequestMapping(value = "/getRegion2", produces={"application/json; charset=UTF-8"},method = RequestMethod.GET)`